# Remove whitespace at the bottom of HTML page when using floating table

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

When I am using floating table of content in R Markdown:

```
title: "HTML page"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---
```

It produces extra whitespace after footer at the bottom of HTML page. Using CSS like:

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

Could not remove the blank space. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by modifying `tocify-extend-page` CSS class:

```
.tocify-extend-page {
  height: 0 !important;
}
```

If you have a separate `style.css` file in your R Project, you only need to add the above code to the file. Otherwise, add the following to your HTML codes:

```
<style>
.tocify-extend-page {
  height: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```